# Websphere Application Server 6.1 for developers console install on RHEL 5 failing

Tags: linux, console, installation, websphere, websphere-6.1

Does anyone know how to get the Websphere Application Server for developers (v6.1) installed via the console?

I'm setting up a build server and the server I have is a RHEL 5.6 server with no Graphical console access (only ssh to a tty console).

One of the projects I need to build on the server relies on WAS 6.1 (fix 23, at least), and as the build runs various WAS tools to generate WSDLs, EJBs, etc. I need to have WebSphere installed. So, I downloaded the developers edition, extracted the tar.gz to a directory and tried to install from there.

I have read the various documents about the silent install and have done as suggested: created a responsefile (called `responsefile.txt`) with the following

```
-OPT silentInstallLicenseAcceptance="true"
-OPT allowNonRootSilentInstall="true"
-OPT installType="installNew"
-OPT installLocation="/home/me/apps/was/v6.1"

#This is only a developer install for builds, so no security, features, or profiles!
-OPT PROF_enableAdminSecurity="false"
-OPT feature="noFeature"
-OPT createProfile="false"
-OPT profileType="none"
-OPT PROF_isDeveloperServer="true"

#Logging settings for the install
-OPT traceFormat=text
-OPT traceLevel=CONFIG
```

When I run the `WAS/install -silent -options "${PWD}/WAS/responsefile.txt`, the script seems to run, then returns to the command line after 5 seconds or so. Similarly, `WAS/install -console -options...` does the same.

I looked through the install script and added logging to show the various vars in use in the script (to see if there were any unexpected values, nope). The setup.jar *is* in the correct directory, and `JAVAHOME`is from the JDK supplied by the WAS installer (`${PWD}/JDK/jre.pak/repository/package.java.jre/java/jre`).

So, I then ran the java command manually:

```
export JAVAHOME=${PWD}/JDK/jre.pak/repository/package.java.jre/java/jre
${JAVAHOME}/bin/java \
   -cp ${PWD}/WAS/setup.jar \
   -Xms265m -Xmx512m \
   run
   -silent \
   -options "${PWD}/WAS/responsefile.txt"
```

This time, various settings were output to the console, but it still returned after about 5 seconds without installing the software (no `/home/me/apps/was` created). Output was;

```
I       Process Type: install
I       Install Type: nonOS400
I       Install Mode: silentMode
I       #Received OPT Properties
#Fri Jul 22 07:21:33 EDT 2011
traceLevel=CONFIG
traceFormat=text
PROF_hostName=dev-ci-svr
silentInstallLicenseAcceptance=true
allowNonRootSilentInstall=true
profileType=none
installLocation=/home/me/apps/was/v6.1
installType=installNew
PROF_enableAdminSecurity=false
feature=noFeature
```

I also tried as `root`, with the same results.

The documentation also mentions a `-console` option, but this only gives the following message

```
The wizard cannot continue because of the following error: Invalid command line option: console is not supported (1001) (403)
```

Has anyone succeeded in installing WebSphere from the Linux command line?

[Edit]
OK, seems to be installing now. It turns out there is an environment var you can set to see more output from the installer `is.debug` (needed to decompile `setup.jar` to see this).

When I run with this defined, I can at least see the problems it's failing over.

Right, in the `responsefile.txt` I needed to remove the `createProfile` option (clashes with `installType`), and disable the OS pre-requisite check by adding `-OPT disableOSPrereqChecking="true"`.

After this it installed. Simples.

[Rant] The setup JAR should at least tell you why it's failing without needing to resort to undocumented settings, or decompiling the JAR.

Comment: How do I mark the question as resolved???

Comment: You should provide the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On advice from home, am providing the answer (same as in the original edit).

It turns out there is an environment var you can set to see more output from the installer is.debug (needed to decompile setup.jar to see this).

When I run with this defined, I can at least see the problems it's failing over.

Right, in the responsefile.txt I needed to remove the createProfile option (clashes with installType), and disable the OS pre-requisite check by adding -OPT disableOSPrereqChecking="true".

After this it installed. Simples.